# Issue with Mocking webclient - getting nullpointer for httpHeader.addAll()

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, spring-webclient

I am trying to mock webclient, but getting Null pointer error for the httpHeaders.addAll() method. Can anyone please help on this.

**Code snippet** :

*Method to be mocked* :

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

NPDetails response = webClient.get().uri(npApiUrl)                              
.headers((httpHeaders>httpHeaders.addAll(tokenProvider.getHttpHeaders())))
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(NPDetails.class)                            
.onErrorMap(Predicate.not(PlatformServiceException.class::isInstance),
ex -> new RuntimeException("Error occurred getting details", ex)).block();
```

*Mocking snippet* :

```
NPDetails mockNPDetails = new NPDetails();

Mockito.when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
Mockito.when(requestBodyUriMock.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
Mockito.when(requestBodyMock.headers(httpHeader -> httpHeader.addAll(tokenProvider.getHttpHeaders()))).thenReturn(requestBodyMock);
Mockito.when(requestBodyMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
Mockito.when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
Mockito.when(responseMock.bodyToMono(
ArgumentMatchers.<Class<NPDetails>>notNull())).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockNPDetails));

NPDetails response = npTenantServiceImpl.getNPDetails(“test”);

Assertions.assertThat(response).isNotNull();
```

*Error Snnipet*:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter.addAll(MultiValueMapAdapter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.addAll(HttpHeaders.java:1677)
```

Comment: `WebClient.builder().build()` is creating a new instance, it is not using any mocks. `webClient.get()` calls the `get` method, but `when(webClient.post())` stubs the `post` method.